# How to check if the current user ID is present (once) in various instances of a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have four models: Post, Comment, Vote, User (Devise).
Users can vote posts and comments. The Vote model has an attribute called `user_id` where the ID of the user who voted the post or comment is stored.

So as users vote, the structure looks like this:

> **Post** (:id = 29)
>
> **Vote** (:user_id = 1), **Vote** (:user_id = 3), **Vote** (:user_id = 5), **Vote** (:user_id = 2)
>
> 4 votes (@post.votes.count)

I would like to have the following:

If the `current_user` ID is present in the `user_id` attribute of the Vote instances of this post, do X.

For example, following the example above, if the `current_user` has ID 3 X will be triggered . If the `current_user` has ID 4, it won't.

Any suggestions to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
if @post.votes.exists?(:user_id => current_user.id)
  # Do something
end
```